# SQL - define a variable that points to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have several queries that drop the proc if it exists, recreate it, and set permissions on it, similar to this:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO    
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

if exists (select * 
           from dbo.sysobjects 
           where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[spMyStoredProcedureName]') 
           and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
drop procedure [dbo].[spMyStoredProcedureName]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMyStoredProcedureName]
AS

/* more proc stuff  */

GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[spMyStoredProcedureName] 
              TO Some_User_Group
```

My question is: is there some way to define a variable for `[dbo].[spMyStoredProcedureName]` so that I can declare it once and refer to the variable?  I need to use the variable two ways - once as a string in the `select` statement and the rest of the time as a reference to the stored proc I'm creating/dropping.

Comment: You can try using a dynamic sql approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your goal is to replace your "several scripts" with just one script that can be used by changing the value of the variable that holds the name of the stored procedure.

If so you could try a dynamic approach:

```
Declare @spMyStoredProcedureName nvarchar(255);

--either use a cursor or whatever means to populate the variable.   
--for this example I will simply set it

SET @spMyStoredProcedureName = '[dbo].[spMyStoredProcedureName]';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SET @sql='
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO    
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

if exists (select * 
           from dbo.sysobjects 
           where id = object_id(N''@spMyStoredProcedureName'') 
           and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
drop procedure @spMyStoredProcedureName
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE @spMyStoredProcedureName
AS

/* more proc stuff  */

GRANT EXECUTE ON @spMyStoredProcedureName 
              TO Some_User_Group
';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@spMyStoredProcedureName', @spMyStoredProcedureName)
EXECUTE(@sql)
```

Note that you'll need to escape all the single quotes in your stored proc code when doing this.   Also I'm not so sure you can use the GO command in dynamic sql.  If not, you'd need to do two separate dynamic statements per stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic sql for your intended ddl statement. A sample implementation below.

```
-- Declare variable to store the procedure name
Declare @proc varchar(100) = 'myProc';

-- Construct the ddl statement
DECLARE @script nvarChar(MAX);
SET @script = 
'
if exists (select * 
           from dbo.sysobjects 
           where id = object_id(N'''+ @proc + ''') 
           and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N''IsProcedure'') = 1)
drop procedure ' + @proc + ';

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE ' + @proc + '
AS
    print ''Hello World!'';
/* more proc stuff  */
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON ' + @proc + '
              TO Some_User_Group;
'

SET @script = 'EXEC (''' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@script, '''', ''''''), 
          'GO', '''); EXEC(''') + ''');'

-- Run the dynamic ddl
EXEC (@script);

-- Test
exec myproc;
```